# Toggle radio show/hide only closest

Tags: jquery

I have a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/esLMh/

Why is the "no" not toggling to hide?

```
$('.hide-show input').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.hide-show').next('.hide-show-yes').toggle(this.value == 'yes');
  $(this).closest('.hide-show').next('.hide-show-no').toggle(this.value == 'no');
});
$('.hide-show input:checked').change(); //trigger correct state onload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` only selects the next immediate sibling of the selected element(*if it matches the specified selector*), based on your markup, you should call two `next` methods for selecting the second target element.

```
$('.hide-show input').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('.hide-show')
           .next('.hide-show-yes').toggle(this.value == 'yes')
           .next('.hide-show-no').toggle(this.value == 'no');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8ycG/

You can also use `nextAll` method but this method is overkill in this case.